# Trying to run a sparql query on quads+triples files, getting error: com.bigdata.rdf.sparql.ast.QuadsOperationInTriplesModeException

Tags: python, sparql, blazegraph

I am using the Blazegraph Database to run a very simple query. For my dataset, I have .ttl and .nq files. I am loading the files using Blazegraph's Bulk Data Loader. Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?g 
WHERE {
 GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o }
}
```

I expect an output of the distinct graph names. However, here is the error I am getting:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.bigdata.rdf.sparql.ast.QuadsOperationInTriplesModeException: Use of WITH and GRAPH constructs in query body is not supported in triples mode.
```

In my RWStore.properties, here are the two main flags for setup (there are more but these are the related ones):

```
com.bigdata.rdf.sail.truthMaintenance=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.quads=true
```

This is how I am loading the files and running the jar:

```
java -Xmx4g -cp /pathto/blazegraph.jar com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader -verbose -namespace kb /pathto/RWStore.properties /pathto/data

java -server -Xmx4g -jar -Djetty.host=0.0.0.0 /pathto/blazegraph.jar
```

Also, here is something to note: I am able to run the same queries when I manually load the files via python (sparql.SPARQLServer.update(file)). I don't get this error then.

Can someone help me with this error? I can't find any solution anywhere!

Comment: when starting the server, don't you have to pass the properties as well to it?

Comment: No, not necessarily.. I've been able to run it without passing the properties file to it. I can give it a try though and put a comment here if something changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! The problem was because of the different format of the files being loaded by BulkDataLoader. Triples don't have a named graph while quads do, and so while querying, there was a mismatch which is the error in my question. This isn't the case when you manually upload the files (via workbench or python).

These are the changes I made:

1. Two properties files, one for quads and one for triples.

quads.properties:

```
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.quads=true
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.statementIdentifiers=false
```

triples.properties:

```
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.quads=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.statementIdentifiers=false
```

2. While using BulkDataLoader:

For .nq files:

```
java -Xmx4g -cp /pathto/blazegraph.jar com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader -verbose -namespace kb /pathto/quads.properties /pathto/data
```

For .ttl files:

```
java -Xmx4g -cp /pathto/blazegraph.jar com.bigdata.rdf.store.DataLoader -verbose -defaultGraph http://ex.org -namespace kb /pathto/triples.properties /pathto/data
```

To start Blazegraph after loading files:

```
java -server -Xmx4g -jar -Djetty.host=0.0.0.0 /pathto/blazegraph.jar
```

Hope this helps others facing a similar issue!